# Rename tag class-bravo to class-b?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

The FAA refers to the different types of airspace as Class A, B, C, D, E, and G.  On the radio, B and D can be easily confused, so we use phonetics (Bravo or Delta), but when written it is not used that way.

I would suggest renaming [class-bravo](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-bravo) to [class-b](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/class-b) and *possibly* adding a tag synonym if it becomes a problem.

Comment: I agree with that. If someone goes to type in class-bravo, class-b would come up before they finished typing bravo anyway.

Comment: Outside the FAA jurisdiction though (which is pretty much most of the world) ;) it is not necessarily referred to as A-G, I know for a fact that it's referred to as Bravo, rather than B, in Germany (although Germany doesn't use Alpha and Bravo airspace, but do use Charlie, Delta, Foxtrot and Golf) Don't get me wrong, I prefer `class-b`, just saying it's not necessarily the most common in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: @roe: Interesting, is it actually **written** as class Bravo in Germany?  It is *referred* to as Class Bravo in the US too, but only when spoken.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This sounds reasonable. The term correctly written "Class B", so it is preferable to use the correct vernacular. Fixed.

Now when users enter the tag (c-l-a-s-s...), the text completion will show them the correct tag to use. Once the site gets moving along (past the private beta), the increased reputation requirements to create *new* tags will make it more difficult to enter the wrong thing. There's really no need to create a tag synonym because the text completion will automatically show them which tag they should be using.

And don't forget to add some helpful 'tag wiki' guidance to make tags even *easier* to use!

[**Improved Tagging**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/08/improved-tagging/)

Comment: I think some people will still try to type in `bravo-airspace` or `charlie-airspace` etc, so a tag synonym would be helpful in that case.

Comment: As in the comment to the question, FAA thinks it's correct, German LBA does not. Does ICAO have an opinion?